# createGlobalMarker() function is not allowed within the current context

Tags: capl

I am attempting to use the function `createGlobalMarker()` in a CAPL script of a CANalyzer configuration. The script is inserted on the Send branch of the configuration.

I am sending frames with periodic content/rate and I'd like to log a marker whenever I'm switching from one signal of the frame to another.

This is a poor man's test setup of sorts.

So far, I cannot use this function in switch cases, timers and signal reception. The documentation only provides an example of the `on key` event, but doesn't describe where the function can be used.

So the question is: where can I use the function? Does it have something to do with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation, the function can only be used in *CANalyzer Analysis Branch*, the equivalent of CANoe's measurement setup.

I.e. right of the Offline/Online switch.

You seem to have placed it in the transmit branch.

As a rule of thumb, everything that is solely related to analysis has to go to the measurement setup.

Comment: that would explain it. however, in my doc version, 12.0 SP2 CANalyzer, it doesn't mention it...

Comment: Just checked with the documentation of 13.0. There it says only in "Analysis Branch". I currently do not have access to older versions.

Comment: it's a documentation issue, thank you for the check!